# Can I remove a '.' from my Gmail username?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I know it doesn't make much of a difference, as Gmail forwards all messages to "john.doe" and "johndoe" to the same inbox, but I don't want it there anymore. The `.` shows up whenever my Gmail username is displayed across Google products.

Comment: That's odd, it typically doesn't show the `.`s in my address (though I'd like it to).  Can you give a specific example of where it shows up?

Comment: I signed up for my Google account with the '.' in my username, and it has been there ever since. Did you also sign up with the period in your username?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Google](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=19870), it is not possible:

> You can't change the email address on your account to an existing
>   Gmail address, but we invite you to add a new Gmail address to your
>   Google Account.